# Create a tkinter image button without a border

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have seen some posts on this topic and have tried the suggestions without success.  I want to create a tkinter button using an image.  The code below creates the button just fine, but it draws a thin border beyond the image that looks ugly. How can I get rid of the button border? I am using Python 3.5 on Mac OS X 10.12.3.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

sDefaultImage = None

def sStockPileObserver():
    print("Button clicked")

def main():
    global sDefaultImage
    sRoot = Tk()
    sMainFrame = ttk.Frame(sRoot, padding="3 3 12 12")
    sMainFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    sMainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    sMainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    sMainFrame.rowconfigure(2, minsize=85)
    sDefaultImage = PhotoImage(file='backDimmed.gif')

    s = ttk.Style()
    bg = s.lookup('TFrame', 'background')
    s.configure("SolitaireCard.TButton", borderwidth=0, background=bg, highlightbackground=bg, \
                          highlightthickness=0, activebackground=bg, activeforeground=bg, padx=0)
    sStockPileButton = ttk.Button(sMainFrame, image=sDefaultImage, style="SolitaireCard.TButton", width=0, command=lambda: sStockPileObserver())
    sStockPileButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E), padx=0)
    return sRoot

sRoot = main()
sRoot.mainloop()
```

Here is what it produces:

[image: Button shown with thin border]

Comment: Perhaps you could put the image in a Label instead of a Button. I suspect that would give you greater control over the border style. If you're thinking "but how would I detect mouse clicks on the label?", you can use the `bind` method for that.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX and Windows you don't have much control over the appearance of buttons.

One solution is to create a button from a label or canvas. You have to add your own bindings to handle clicks, but that's pretty simple to do. For the most part, the bindings simply change the border from raised to lowered, and then call a function when you finish the click.